# What is the difference between #!/bin/bash and #!/bin/expect in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I have written expect script and shell script for ftp connection.Could you tell me which one is better or fast?

**This expect script**

```
expect << EOF
spawn sftp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
expect "User Name :"
send "username\r"
expect "password:"
send "password\r"
expect "sftp> "
send "cd in\r"
expect "sftp> "
send "mkdir $current_date_$pharmacy_code\r"
expect "sftp> "
send "cd $current_date_$pharmacy_code\r"
expect "sftp> "
send "put $1\r"
expect "sftp> "
send "exit\r"
EOF
```

or

**Shell Script**

```
sftp $host << EOF
quote USER $user
quote PASS $password
cd in
mkdir $current_date_$pharmacy_code
cd $current_date_$pharmacy_code
put $1
exit
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

They are different languages with different libraries.

Expect is a library for Tcl, and both can run on a variety of operating systems.

Bash is a standard command interpreter for Linux and not usually found on many other operating systems.

As for which is faster, time them and see.  However, speed alone may not be the only pertinent criteria:  error handling, reliability, maintainability, portability, etc. may be larger factors in choosing an implementation.

Comment: Git has a cool bash shell for use on windows.  Runs like a command window but has linux commands.

Comment: In addition to being available on MS Windows (via git and cygwin), bash is also commonly used on Mac OSX.